# Spring framework scope - Is it a misnomer?

Tags: spring, spring-framework-beans

I know there is a term `Bean scope` in Spring framework, and for some reasons it is confusing me, mainly because of the term `scope`, because we have this terms (scope) in languages, like `C`, `Java` applied to a variable scope (that is where a variable is visible).

I know there are five bean scope, and I am not asking explanation on them, I am not clear on what `Bean scope` means. Can anyone help me understand what does this term mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In programming languages scope of the variables defines **where** in the code, the variable can be reached.

- Global variables can be accesed from everywhere.
- Function parameters or local variables can be accesed only in the function.

In Spring framework scope of the bean defines **when** during the application runtime we are dealing with the same object.

- Singleton scoped bean is an object that is unique to the whole application. Like global variable in programming languages.
- Session scoped bean is an object that is unique to the session.
- Request scoped bean is an object that is unique to the request. Like function parameters.
- Prototype scoped bean is not unique to anything. Every time you get it, you have a new copy. Hard to compare but it can be a heap allocated variable.

In computer science, the **scope** term  is overloaded, the same as the term **interface**. You can have a Go or Java interface as well as PCI or ISA.

Well, the term **overload** is also overloaded.

Comment: Thanks a ton for answer, made things clearer now. Appreciate your time to help.